# Magento 2: Update Billing Address info fields

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml, forms, sort

Sometimes, when the checkout loads, the Region input field is out of position and is placed before all of the other inputs (before firstname input field) in both the Shipping Step (**Shipping address**) and Payment Step (**Billing address**).

> To fix this for the Shipping address fieldset, I specified the Region field sort order in the `checkout_index_index.xml` thus:

```
...
<item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                    <!-- Place the Region input above City and Post Code -->
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
                                </item>                                                                  
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
...
```

I'd also like to specify the sort order for the Region of the Billing Address, but I can't seem to find where to update the sort order for region.

Anyone know where it'd be, or the xml structure I'd need to add to the `checkout_index_index.xml`?

Comment: Yes u need to override in Your Custom Theme `magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\Magento_Checkout\layout\checkout_index_index.xml`

Comment: This was already done – see above